# How to Format Code in Dynamically Created .cs File

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I have dynamically created a new .cs file using the following method:

```
// Create the new file. 
using (FileStream newFile = File.Create(path))
    {
        //Get info for the file
        Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("contents");

        // Add information to the file.
        newFile.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
        System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm.Close();
    }
```

This works great and all my info is being displayed how I want, except the code is not formatted properly. All the text is aligned to the left and there is no indention. Is there a way to fix this, or perhaps another method I can use to create the cs file that would result in a properly formatted .cs file?

Comment: Not sure answer on this, but an FYI for you, when you have a file open in VS ctrl +K, D will auto format it for you (if you get no luck with any answers)

Comment: @alykins: FYI for your information, I hope that was a joke.

Comment: not sure, but hope this can help..
https://github.com/codecadwallader/codemaid

Comment: How was it a joke? Rather than figure out how to stream read the file and do all that, a few key strokes and it is auto formatted if he gets no answer telling him an easier way to do it. Thinking through streaming through every line of code and figuring out every nested statement and brace would be a pain- I'm offering an alternative if he gets no quick already-been-done replies or has to do on own and decides is too much of a pain in * to do.  ?

Comment: Ironic that you ask about formatting and your question does not even have proper formatting.  That does not create a .cs file.  "contents" is not a valid .cs file.   "contents" has no indent.

Comment: @Blam I just put "contents" in there as a place holder. In my actual code it is a function that creates the actual contents that appear in .cs file. The same goes for "path". It points at a file path that does not exist to create a new file ie. C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\New File Test\generatedFile.cs

Comment: Is the actual contents formatted?  Show some actual code.  And format the question.

Comment: Tab the content based on the number of `{` and `}`. I will not write that code for you.

Comment: that seems awefully convoluted code just to write a text file.

Comment: Download [NArrange](http://www.narrange.net/). Its an open source C# beautifier. You can either use this code to roll your own beautifier code or you could call it externally from your application to format the code.